# Installing Plex on a Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: raspbian-lite, media-server

According to https://support.plex.tv/articles/235974187-enable-repository-updating-for-supported-linux-server-distributions/ and a few other sitesI should do a

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https

echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
```

then a

```
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

But I get this warning:

Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

I've asked about this in the official Plex forum, but no answers.
Instead I downloaded the .deb package from their website, copied it to the RPI on an external drive attached via SMB, then ran a

```
sudo dpkg -i plexmediaserver_1.25.2.5319-c43dc0277_arm64.deb
```

Everything works fine, aparently. My question is this:

When using the first method, I should install plex with

```
sudo apt install plexmediaserver
```

, meaning that in the future, when I run a sudo apt upgrade, also the Plex software will be updated. But with the method I used, this is not an option. There is an option in the server software, to do an update. I have no idea how this method works. But as Plex releases new updates fairly often, I just want to make sure I can update the software this way.

And that's my question. I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

**If a package is available in the repository**, it is always best to install it using this sequence:

```
sudo apt update 
...
sudo apt upgrade
...
sudo apt install <packagename>
```

You can check for the availability of a package in `apt` using this command:

```
apt-cache search <package name>
```

When I check for `plexmediaserver`:

```
apt-cache search plexmediaserver
```

There are no results - which means that there is no `apt` package for `plexmediaserver` - which also means that `apt update` & `apt upgrade` won't work - you'll have to rely on **some other mechanism** for updates. The package itself may have this **update/upgrade** feature built in.

Comment: The initial commands I wrote to be used, do exactly that - add plex's server to places for apk to download from. And there should be a Plex package in the repository, I've been told. But it's rarely updated, hence the way I tried is the recommended method. It gives the latest Plex files, every time you run apt upgrade.

Comment: @Akyhne: Don't know what to say... `plexmediaserver` is not in RPi-buster's repo according to `apt-cache search`. As far as getting upgraded with apt, all I can say is that's something I've never heard of.